# Service fabric package error during code package activation

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I have a ServiceFabric Application running on 5 nodes. I was in the process of restarting the nodes one by one to get rid of a known [Memory Leakage problem](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/695).
Restarting node 1 went fine.

Ran into problems when restarting node 2.
On node 2 there is a Stateful Service with 1 (large) partition that ended up in Quarum Loss.

> Unhealthy deployed service package: ApplicationName='fabric:/MyApplication', ServiceManifestName='ServicePkg', ServicePackageActivationId='', NodeName='node02', AggregatedHealthState='Error'.

Deleted the Service from the node, which was fine but *ServicePkg* is still lingering on that node, with the following Error

> Error event: SourceId='System.Hosting', Property='CodePackageActivation:Code:EntryPoint'. There was an error during CodePackage activation.The service host terminated with exit code:2148734499

For now I managed to get the service started on other nodes as long as I allowed for more Replicas, but as long as the error on Node 2 exists, upgrades will fail.

**Can this be fixed without a complete purge on Node 2?**